# Is there any way to link "starting" and "completed" events?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

In SQL Server Extended Events, is there any way of linking a "starting" event, such as `rpc_starting`, with a "completed" event, such as `rpc_completed`?  For example, is there anything like a correlation ID which would uniquely identify a call to SQL Server?

I'd like to query the recorded events, to get the start time of a call, from `rpc_starting`, and its duration, from `rpc_completed`.  So far I haven't found any way to uniquely link the start and end of the same call.

I thought the `request_id` action might work but it seems to come out as 0 for the events I've looked at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Causality tracking can do that for you, below is an example:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION TestCausality
ON SERVER
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.auto_stats,
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed,
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_starting,
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed,
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_recompile,
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_starting
    ADD TARGET package0.event_file
    (SET filename = N'TestCausality')
WITH
(
    TRACK_CAUSALITY = ON
);
```

After the event is created I run a simple TSQL just as an example:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.CommandLog
```

Then in the GUI of your extended event view you can add "Attach_Activity_Id.GUID", with this you can link your statements to each other.
Looks like this: [image: Causality SQL Server]

Comment: I've had a play with this.  It's not perfect, since multiple statements can have the same attach_activity_Id.guid.  However, I think it's good enough to be able to find the completed event for a given starting event.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the start time by subtracting the duration from the timestamp so you don't need to collect the `rpc_starting` events.  Other than that, see Yannick's suggestion to use TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON.